# Custom Options Update Magento Product Image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image, magento

I’ve been working on this issue for a long time and it’s the only thing keeping my Magento store from launching at this point. I’ve tried a number of extensions to accomplish this and I still can’t figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Basically, my store offers a particular item that is built to order. I need to find a way to update the product’s image when a new selection is made to one of the options via dropdown box. See the links below for a couple of examples. I can accomplish this through either Custom Options or a Bundled Product, whichever will allow me to add new items when necessary.

Examples of what I’m looking for:

- http://knockaround.com/shop/sunglasses/custom/custom-premium
- http://www.voodoocontrollers.com/custom-xbox-controllers.html

If anyone can help me out with coding these features, or pointing me in the right direction for a tutorial or an explanation of how to go about it I would really appreciate it…

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Joe. 
If understand you right, you need to change the main product image when a user chooses one of the available options. The best way to do this is to create a transparent image that will overlay the main picture. As a result, the product picture will be updated in accordance with the selected custom option. So, store visitors will see the product variation exactly how it should look like.

You can try to code this method manually, or use the extension offered here https://store.orange35.com/image-constructor-for-custom-options-for-magento